# A $D$- supercontinuous function that is not $D_{\delta}$- supercontinuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am looking for a $D$- supercontinuous function that is not $D_{\delta}$-supercontinuous where in D- supercontinuous inverse imafge of open set is open $F_{\sigma}$ and for $D_{\delta}$-supercontinuous functions inverse image of open set is regular $F_{\sigma}$.

> A **regular $F_{\sigma}$ set** is a set $S \subset X$ such that S is a union of a sequence of closed sets whose interiors contain $S$ i.e. $S=\cup_{1}^{\infty} F_n= \cup_{1}^{\infty} {F_n}^{\circ}$.

Both of these functions are stronger from continuity and further $D_{\delta}$-supercontinuous  is stronger than $D$-supercontinuous, but a counterexample is not trivial to me. I have looked into thomas' space, skyline space etc where such a counterexample is obtainable for $D^*$-supercontinuous (definition not necessary).

A countinuous but not D-supercontinuos is easily constructed using two spaces $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $Y=\{x,y,z\}$ and then specifically defining two different topologies on them.

Answer (score 1):

For $X=\mathbb{N}$ by considering cofinite topology. Identity function is such a counterexample.